# jquery mouseup + not, not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

http://jsfiddle.net/xQKNh/6/

Here is my code, I want to select words on mouseup, except some `div` by `id`.

I have tried:

`$("body:not(#protect)").mouseup(function() {`

`$("body").not("#protect").mouseup(function() {`

`$("body:not('#protect')").mouseup(function() {`

But the `not.selection` not working for the `$('body').mouseup`.

BTW, in my main page, the selection area not only the `div#content-area`, just for the question, I left one `div` for test.

So what is the best way to protect one div out of the whole body mouseup by jquery? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `mouseup` events bubble, you can just select the `<div>` then selectively filter out events from `#protected` using `e.stopPropagation()` to stop the bubbling. [See jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/xQKNh/7/)

```
$("#content-area").mouseup(function() {
    var selection = getSelected();
    if(selection && (selection = selection.toString().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''))) {
        $('#show-text').html(selection)
    }
});

$("#protect").mouseup(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[You could cancel the selection, too.](http://jsfiddle.net/xQKNh/10/)

P.S. You should use `obj.toString()` or `String(obj)` instead of `new String(obj)`.

Comment: such a great help. Thank you very much. Now I should go out with my friends. Happy new year.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").mouseup(function(e) {
        if (e.target.id != 'protect') {
            var selection = getSelected();
            if(selection && (selection = new String(selection).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''))) {
            $('#show-text').html(selection)
        }
    }
  });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/xQKNh/11/)

Comment: Not enough jQuery, you should be using `!$(e.target).is("#protect")`. -1 (just kidding.)